# Magento get Seller SKU In invoice

Tags: magento-1.9

We are using Marketplace in my website also some product have more then one seller. Even every seller have unique **SKU**

```
<?php $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
                $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('mpassignproduct'=>'marketplace_assignproduct'))->where('mpassignproduct.mpassignproduct_id=?', $res['mpassignproduct_id']);
                $mpassignproduct =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);     
                if(count($mpassignproduct)) {
                 foreach($mpassignproduct as $assignproduct)
                   {   $name = $name."<p style='float:left;'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($products->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$orderdproname."</a> <strong>".$assignproduct['sku']." </strong> <span>".intval($res['magequantity'])."</span>&nbsp;</p>";

                   }
                } else {
                     $name = $name."<p style='float:left;'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($products->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$orderdproname."</a> <strong>".$products->getSku()." </strong> <span>".intval($res['magequantity'])."</span>&nbsp;</p>";
                      }


                    }
```

We used above code to `Model/saleslist.php` it's working fine but in PDF Invoice it's showing Base Sku how to get seller **SKU**

```
default.php





class Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Draw item line
     */
    public function draw()
    {
        $order  = $this->getOrder();
        $item   = $this->getItem();
        $pdf    = $this->getPdf();
        $page   = $this->getPage();
        $lines  = array();

        $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
    $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$order->getOrderId()); 

    foreach($_collection as $res){
      $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');




 $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('mpassignproduct'=>'marketplace_assignproduct'))->where('mpassignproduct.mpassignproduct_id_id=?', $res->getMpassignproductId());
 $mpassignproduct =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord); 
 if(count($mpassignproduct)) {
 foreach($mpassignproduct as $assignproduct)
   { 
    $sku=$assignproduct['sku'];
   }


}
print_r($res);
exit;
}


        // draw Product name
        $lines[0] = array(array(
            'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($item->getName(), 35, true, true),
            'feed' => 35,
        ));

        // draw SKU
        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($this->getSku($item), 17),
            'feed'  => 290,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        // draw QTY
        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => $item->getQty() * 1,
            'feed'  => 435,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        // draw item Prices
        $i = 0;
        $prices = $this->getItemPricesForDisplay();
        $feedPrice = 395;
        $feedSubtotal = $feedPrice + 170;
        foreach ($prices as $priceData){
            if (isset($priceData['label'])) {
                // draw Price label
                $lines[$i][] = array(
                    'text'  => $priceData['label'],
                    'feed'  => $feedPrice,
                    'align' => 'right'
                );
                // draw Subtotal label
                $lines[$i][] = array(
                    'text'  => $priceData['label'],
                    'feed'  => $feedSubtotal,
                    'align' => 'right'
                );
                $i++;
            }
            // draw Price
            $lines[$i][] = array(
                'text'  => $priceData['price'],
                'feed'  => $feedPrice,
                'font'  => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right'
            );
            // draw Subtotal
            $lines[$i][] = array(
                'text'  => $priceData['subtotal'],
                'feed'  => $feedSubtotal,
                'font'  => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right'
            );
            $i++;
        }

        // draw Tax
        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
            'feed'  => 495,
            'font'  => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        // custom options
        $options = $this->getItemOptions();
        if ($options) {
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                // draw options label
                $lines[][] = array(
                    'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split(strip_tags($option['label']), 40, true, true),
                    'font' => 'italic',
                    'feed' => 35
                );

                if ($option['value']) {
                    if (isset($option['print_value'])) {
                        $_printValue = $option['print_value'];
                    } else {
                        $_printValue = strip_tags($option['value']);
                    }
                    $values = explode(', ', $_printValue);
                    foreach ($values as $value) {
                        $lines[][] = array(
                            'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($value, 30, true, true),
                            'feed' => 40
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $lineBlock = array(
            'lines'  => $lines,
            'height' => 20
        );

        $page = $pdf->drawLineBlocks($page, array($lineBlock), array('table_header' => true));
        $this->setPage($page);
    }
}
```

**Output**

### Array ( [entity_id] => 1800 [state] => invoice [status] => invoice [coupon_code] => [protect_code] => 1e81cb [shipping_description] => Shipping - Charges : [is_virtual] => 0 [store_id] => 1 [customer_id] => 262 [base_discount_amount] => 0.0000 [base_discount_canceled] => [base_discount_invoiced] => 0.0000 [base_discount_refunded] => [base_grand_total] => 200.0000 [base_shipping_amount] => 0.0000 [base_shipping_canceled] => [base_shipping_invoiced] => 0.0000 [base_shipping_refunded] => [base_shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000 [base_shipping_tax_refunded] => [base_subtotal] => 200.0000 [base_subtotal_canceled] => [base_subtotal_invoiced] => 0.0000 [base_subtotal_refunded] => [base_tax_amount] => 0.0000 [base_tax_canceled] => [base_tax_invoiced] => 0.0000 [base_tax_refunded] => [base_to_global_rate] => 1.0000 [base_to_order_rate] => 1.0000 [base_total_canceled] => [base_total_invoiced] => 200.0000 [base_total_invoiced_cost] => 0.0000 [base_total_offline_refunded] => [base_total_online_refunded] => [base_total_paid] => 200.0000 [base_total_qty_ordered] => [base_total_refunded] => [discount_amount] => 0.0000 [discount_canceled] => [discount_invoiced] => 0.0000 [discount_refunded] => [grand_total] => 200.0000 [shipping_amount] => 0.0000 [shipping_canceled] => [shipping_invoiced] => 0.0000 [shipping_refunded] => [shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000 [shipping_tax_refunded] => [store_to_base_rate] => 1.0000 [store_to_order_rate] => 1.0000 [subtotal] => 200.0000 [subtotal_canceled] => [subtotal_invoiced] => 200.0000 [subtotal_refunded] => [tax_amount] => 0.0000 [tax_canceled] => [tax_invoiced] => 0.0000 [tax_refunded] => [total_canceled] => [total_invoiced] => 200.0000 [total_offline_refunded] => [total_online_refunded] => [total_paid] => 200.0000 [total_qty_ordered] => 1.0000 [total_refunded] => [can_ship_partially] => [can_ship_partially_item] => [customer_is_guest] => 0 [customer_note_notify] => 1 [billing_address_id] => 3599 [customer_group_id] => 1 [edit_increment] => [email_sent] => 1 [forced_shipment_with_invoice] => [gift_message_id] => [payment_auth_expiration] => [paypal_ipn_customer_notified] => [quote_address_id] => [quote_id] => 6948 [shipping_address_id] => 3600 [adjustment_negative] => [adjustment_positive] => [base_adjustment_negative] => [base_adjustment_positive] => [base_shipping_discount_amount] => 0.0000 [base_subtotal_incl_tax] => 200.0000 [base_total_due] => 0.0000 [payment_authorization_amount] => [shipping_discount_amount] => 0.0000 [subtotal_incl_tax] => 200.0000 [total_due] => 0.0000 [weight] => 1.0000 [customer_dob] => [increment_id] => 100001841 [applied_rule_ids] => [base_currency_code] => INR [customer_email] => besttoyskids@gmail.com [customer_firstname] => kids [customer_lastname] => d [customer_middlename] => [customer_prefix] => [customer_suffix] => [customer_taxvat] => [discount_description] => [ext_customer_id] => [ext_order_id] => [global_currency_code] => INR [hold_before_state] => [hold_before_status] => [order_currency_code] => INR [original_increment_id] => [relation_child_id] => [relation_child_real_id] => [relation_parent_id] => [relation_parent_real_id] => [remote_ip] => 27.34.240.114 [shipping_method] => mpperproductshipping_mpperproductshipping [store_currency_code] => INR [store_name] => Main Website Default Wide English [x_forwarded_for] => [customer_note] => [created_at] => 2016-01-11 11:12:42 [updated_at] => 2016-01-11 12:28:01 [total_item_count] => 1 [customer_gender] => [base_custbalance_amount] => [currency_base_id] => [currency_code] => [currency_rate] => [custbalance_amount] => [is_hold] => [is_multi_payment] => [real_order_id] => [tax_percent] => [tracking_numbers] => [hidden_tax_amount] => 0.0000 [base_hidden_tax_amount] => 0.0000 [shipping_hidden_tax_amount] => 0.0000 [base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt] => 0.0000 [hidden_tax_invoiced] => 0.0000 [base_hidden_tax_invoiced] => 0.0000 [hidden_tax_refunded] => [base_hidden_tax_refunded] => [shipping_incl_tax] => 0.0000 [base_shipping_incl_tax] => 0.0000 [coupon_rule_name] => [mpcashondelivery] => 0.0000 [payment_authorization_expiration] => [forced_do_shipment_with_invoice] => [base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount] => 0.0000 )

Comment: have you added above code in phtml file?

Comment: Ya but it's not working

Comment: then need to add this code in order pdf model file

Comment: @Abdul How to add is it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy this

`app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php`

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php
```

add your sku at line 54. add your code here..

```
    $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
    $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$order->getEntityId()); 

    foreach($_collection as $res){
      $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');




 $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('mpassignproduct'=>'marketplace_assignproduct'))->where('mpassignproduct.mpassignproduct_id_id=?', $res->getMpassignproductId()
 )
 ;
 $mpassignproduct =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord); 
 if(count($mpassignproduct)) {
 foreach($mpassignproduct as $assignproduct)
   { 
    $sku=$assignproduct['sku'];
   }



  }else {
 $sku=$this->getSku($item);
    }
$lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($sku, 17),
            'feed'  => 290,
            'align' => 'right'
        );
```

Comment: it showing Base sku only not seller sku

Comment: add here your sku. you have orderid add your collection and get that.

Comment: How to add here

Comment: updated the answer check and feedback..

Comment: it shows error Call to a member function getId() on a non-object

Comment: `$order->getOrderId()` try this...

Comment: Call to a member function getOrderId() on a non-object

Comment: can you do `print_r($order);` and check for order id

Comment: where i can print this

Comment: add above mu code and after use exit; where you are adding this code?

Comment: i add default.php

Comment: you can see on line 41 `$order` print that..

Comment: i updated question where i have to add this

Comment: I will check  it and provide answer

Comment: ok i waiting for your response

Comment: On mobile right now update will later

Comment: in this pdf there is not item code here check where is item code is coming and put code there..

Comment: magento default pdf will have this ?

Comment: yes the file i mention in my question paste code there and check..

Comment: I added after that nothing display in sku

Comment: I added in default invoice pdf but sku not display

Comment: use exit check magento is using default or not?

Comment: Where i have to use after sku?

Comment: I update my default.php

Comment: check this is called in pdd or not use echo and exit this will tell u

Comment: I don't know exactly where i have to use

Comment: Yes this file only i delete all code then it throw error after revert back it's download invoice pdf in local machine

Comment: it's front end seller generate invoice from front end it download local machine

Comment: add code here which i provided

Comment: After that sku field is empty in pdf

Comment: debug it print_r($res); check you getting some result?

Comment: Where i want to add this ??? Please tell me

Comment: Please update the code i added print_r($res); but it download pdf only

Comment: use exit after the loop..

Comment: Chek my updated question. Is it right?

Comment: move it after the closed `}`

Comment: It showing blank page

Comment: `print_r($order->getData());` and post the output in question

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: Ya thanks it's working but how to add else condition product is not assigned?

Comment: updated the answer kindly check it..

Comment: Thanks for supporting one more problem is there i make a new question mail also getting base sku only not assign sku. is it possible to fetch

Comment: everything is possible...

Comment: ok i rise new question for that can you please help on that

Comment: i will try my best to do that..

Comment: Can you please chaeck this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96805/magento-get-seller-sku-in-order-mail