# Magento get Seller SKU In order Mail

Tags: magento-1.9, email, sales-order, email-templates

We are using Marketplace in my website also some product have more then one seller. Even every seller have unique **SKU**.

While Place order Customer got a mail that mail contain only Base seller sku not Assign seller sku. How to fetch Assign seller **SKU IN Mail**

**Default.phtml**

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>

<?php 

    $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
    $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$order->getEntityId()); 

    foreach($_collection as $res){
      $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');




 $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('mpassignproduct'=>'marketplace_assignproduct'))->where('mpassignproduct.mpassignproduct_id_id=?', $res->getMpassignproductId()
 )
 ;
 $mpassignproduct =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord); 
 if(count($mpassignproduct)) {
 foreach($mpassignproduct as $assignproduct)
   { 
    $sku=$assignproduct['sku'];
   }

 }else {
$sku=$this->getSku($item);
}}



?>
<tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <strong style="font-size:11px;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
        <?php if ($this->getItemOptions()): ?>
        <dl style="margin:0; padding:0;">
            <?php foreach ($this->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
            <dt><strong><em><?php echo $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
            <dd style="margin:0; padding:0 0 0 9px;">
                <?php echo nl2br($option['value']) ?>
            </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $addInfoBlock = $this->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
        <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
            <?php echo $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getSku($_item)) ?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"><?php echo $_item->getQtyOrdered()*1 ?></td>
    <td align="right" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesPriceExclTax($_order->getStore()) || $this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
                <span class="label"><?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax'); ?>:</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>


            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
                <br />
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <br />
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesPriceInclTax($_order->getStore()) || $this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
                <br /><span class="label"><?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax'); ?>:</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getSubtotalInclTax($_item); ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getRowWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
                <br />
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getRowWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php if ($_item->getGiftMessageId() && $_giftMessage = $this->helper('giftmessage/message')->getGiftMessage($_item->getGiftMessageId())): ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" style=" border-bottom:2px solid #CCCCCC; padding:3px 9px;">
        <strong style="color:#444444; font-size:11px;"><?php echo $this->__('Gift Message') ?></strong>
        <?php echo $this->__('From:'); ?> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?><br />
        <?php echo $this->__('To:'); ?> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?><br />
        <strong><?php echo $this->__('Message:'); ?></strong><br /><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```

copy  to your theme

```
 app/design/frontend/yourpakcage/yourtheme/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```

add this after `<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>`

```
$_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
     $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$_order->getEntityId());
$_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageproid',$_item->getProductId());  

    foreach($_collection as $res){
      $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');




 $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('mpassignproduct'=>'marketplace_assignproduct'))->where('mpassignproduct.mpassignproduct_id_id=?', $res->getMpassignproductId()
 )
 ;
 $mpassignproduct =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord); 
 if(count($mpassignproduct)) {
 foreach($mpassignproduct as $assignproduct)
   { 
    $sku=$assignproduct['sku'];
   }

 }else {
$sku=$_item->getSku();
}}
```

Comment: After add this code i can't able to place order. it's not redirect sucess page

Comment: I update my default.phtml

Comment: updated the answer there was a error check it now

Comment: same you will do for invoice and shipment..

Comment: Back end also i need to get assign seller sku Check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96832/magento-get-seller-sku-in-back-end

Comment: i have problem in this mail actullay i order two product 1 is assigned product another one is some product but problem is in mail same sku showing in bothe product

Comment: can you tell this table primary key `marketplace/saleslist`

Comment: i updated table structure here

Comment: `mageproid` contain the product id can u confirm that?

Comment: sorry i did n't get

Comment: table column did it contain the product id

Comment: yes it have some product id(like assign product id)

Comment: updated the answer replace in other places too

Comment: i need to change fully or part of the code

Comment: add this line `$_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageproid',$_item->getProductId()); `